# Ionic 2 Moment JS with Moment TimeZones

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, momentjs, typescript-typings

I'm working on using `moment.js with typescript`. I ran the following commands

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
npm install @types/moment @types/moment-timezone --save
```

but for some reason in the `formattime` function, moment is undefined. I'm not getting any errors from my IDE regarding my import of moment and I can see both `moment` and `moment-timezone` are in the `npm` folder. I've been crawling through post but I'm not seeing much helpful information. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class Utils {

    text: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello Utils Component');
    }


    //This function take the time in MS and the timezone and coverts it
    //@params time - time in milliseconds
    //@params tz - the timezone
    //@paramz isZoneAbbr - true if the zone abbr should be displayed
    //@return - return formattedTime
    public formatTime(time, tz, isZoneAbbr): string {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(moment));
        return "";
        // var formattedTime = moment.tz(time, tz);
        // if (isZoneAbbr) {
        //     return formattedTime.format('h:mm a z');
        // }
        // return formattedTime.format('h:mm a');
    };
}
```

Comment: I have tried my import statement as both `import * as moment from 'moment';` & `import moment from 'moment';`

Comment: dont you need [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) aswell

Comment: @gerdi no angular-moment is just pipes mostly. You should install actual moment in npm since you only installed moment-timezones & types

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to reference as `moment-timezone` and not `moment` because it is not the `moment` package

```
import * as momentTz from 'moment-timezone';
```

Comment: I tried this as well but I'm still getting undefined

Comment: what is moment timezone called in your `package.json` file?

Comment: I have `"moment": "^2.18.1"`   `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.13"` I also added  `"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34"`